# Increment var in td

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to increment a var when I add a new tr

***Table***

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr> 
        <td id="count"></td>
        <td><select><option value="1">1</option></select></td>
        <!--obviously some more options-->
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="addfield()">Add</button>
```

***Script***

```
<script>
var row = 1;

function addfield() {       
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = row;
    $("#myTable").find('tbody').append($('<tr>').append($('<td id="count">')).append($('<td><select><option value="1">1</option></select>')));
    row++;
}
</script>
```

What's happening is, that the script is incrementing the first 'td id="count"'-Tag when adding a new 'tr'-Tag instead of incrementing the next 'td'-Tag. Additionally it doesn't show the count in the new generated 'td'-Tag. 
What am I missing?

Comment: It's incrementing the previous row because you call `document.getElementById("count")`, which will get the last element with the id "count" in the DOM *at the time*. Since you haven't appended the new one yet, it increments the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first off let me go ahead and say that I blew up your HTML structure because it looks to me like you are using a table to do something that is not tabular, so I changed the structure to be divs. I also took the incrementing out of your script and used CSS counters to get the same effect. if using a table to hold your data is critical after all, then I guess you won't choose this answer.
HTML

```
<div id="myTable">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cellish"><select><option value="1">1</option></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="addfield()">Add</button>
```

CSS

```
body {
  counter-reset: count;
}
.cellish {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cellish::before {
  content: counter(count) " ";
  counter-increment: count;
}
```

JS

```
function addfield() {       
    $("#myTable").append($('<div class="row">')).append($('<div class="cellish"><select><option value="1">1</option></select>'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use the same id multiple times in html elements.
Change like this:

```
$("#myTable").find('tbody').append($('<tr>').append($('<td><select><option value="1">1</option></select>')));
```